# How to prevent a Callable from starvation against long running and heavy tasks?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

We built an NLP application which uses "heavy", long running document information extraction threads which are used over the whole lifetime of the application. The result (lets say 20-120 small objects per document) is then put in a blockingqueue and indexed into elasticsearch by another component. Since the extractors need about 3 minutes for one document the indexer is idling most of the time and works very fast. We have `n` cpu cores available.

Currently we simply submit everything (every component is a callable) into a fixedThreadPool with `n+1`; i.e. we set up `n` extraction callables. This works quite fine, however it seems that either one of the extractors is starving if we submit the ingester first, or the indexer is pulling from the queue almost at the very end of the application's lifetime.

How can we ensure that the indexer checks the blockingqueue "from time to time" while keeping itself out of the way of the extractors to maximize application performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you have n CPUs and use thread pool with n+1 tasks then at least one thread will be waiting for resources. You can try to use thread pool with n threads. And regarding **indexer us pulling from queue at the very end** indexed cannot pull from empty blocking queue. It will wait for elements to become available. And once elements are available it will take them from the queue

Comment: If we use n=4 CPU cores and are adding the indexer frist only 3 extractors will work at all (according to log output). And we are aware of the fact that the thread blocks if take() is called on an empty queue; it's just that the indexer, if its started after the extractors, runs only when an extractor callable finished; so we observe almost sequential behaviour from the indexer when using a lot of documents.

Comment: Thread pool starts next tasks only when currently executing tasks are finished. If you have 4 threads and submit elindexer and several extractors then only 3 extractors will work. Once any of them finished next extractor will be started and so on. Thread pool with n threads can execute only n tasks concurrently. New tasks will be kicked off when free slot appears